# iOS FacebookSDK Video Upload

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to upload a video from my iOS app to Facebook and I am using the code:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               videoData, @"video.mp4",
                               @"video/mp4", @"contentType",
                               @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                               @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                               nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result, NSError *error)
 {
     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                           completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                               if(!error)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"SUCCESS RESULT: %@", result);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                               }

}];
```

But I am getting the error:

FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'me/videos': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.

ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Can any one please help me?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this Issue ?

Comment: i was not able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Log the access token to see if you have a valid one:

```
NSLog(@"AccessToken:%@ ",FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken);
```

You need to be logged into your app via Facebook and need to have the `publish_actions` permission granted before you can make a POST request of any sort. 
Once you have the access token, to quickly verify if it is valid and has the appropriate permissions, use the [access token debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token).